# Unknown hardware issue mostly affecting HDs

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure

**Specs** (copy pasting from Speccy)

**Operating System**
Windows 10 Pro 64-bit

**CPU**
AMD FX-6300 Vishera 32nm Technology

**RAM**
8.00GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @ 669MHz (2 4GB sticks)

**Motherboard**
ASUSTeK Computer INC. M5A78L-M LX/BR (AM3R2)

**Graphics**
E2041 (1600x900@60Hz) 2048MB ATI AMD Radeon R7 200 Series (Gigabyte)

**Storage**
298GB Seagate ST3320418AS ATA Device (SATA) - let's call this "HD1"
931GB Seagate ST1000DM003-1SB102 ATA Device (SATA) - let's call this "HD2"

Some time ago while trying to launch a game, my computer suddenly restarted with no warnings or apparent issues, after trying to launch the game again I got a message saying the game was "moved" or "deleted", that was when I first saw my HD2 wasn't showing up under "This PC" anymore, there were no problems until this point. (note: HD2 wasn't the boot drive at this point).

At first I just assumed HD2 was problematic so I tried moving games from it to HD1, no success. At this point my PC would start freezing, resetting or getting BSODs kind of randomly, mostly after some time of use. I tried running cmd commands such as wmic and chkdsk but they never pointed errors in any HD. Because of the BSODs and PC freezes I thought HD1 was the problematic one and it was affecting HD2, or something else entirely.

I started trying lesser intensive things such as watching videos and playing browser games to see how my computer would react but the random freezes/BSODs didn't stop, not only that, booting alone started being a pain. HDs would stop getting detected, BSODs would keep happening while booting with the error code as "inacessible boot device" (it boots properly after some more attempts), and when the BSOD happens while using the computer, the error message is "critical process died".

I've tried resetting the BIOS, using different SATA cables and different ports but no difference at all. HD tests through cmd commands or even SeaTools never detects a problem when they can run properly, as if my HDs just decides when they'll get detected and when they won't. SeaTools mentioned the possibility of a cable problem.

While in use, simple tasks such as trying to open Google Chrome or even Windows' own system features *CAN* make my disk usage (looking at it through Task Manager) jump to 100% or so, in these cases, read/write speeds and average response time remains at 0 or at very low values; if I wait it usually goes back to normal after a while and the program works, but that's limited to non-intensive things such as a browser, games are still a no-go…

As of now I'm using HD2 as my boot drive since HD1 feels more vulnerable to freezing or getting a BSOD.

Extra info:

I tested my RAM just in case, tried 1 stick at a time and it didn't make a difference in the issue.

Before dying from BSODs, struggling to boot through BSODs or simply freezing mid usage, whichever HD I have for boot makes clicky and/or screechy-ish noises, specially HD1, HD2 seems to be more "resistent" all-around.

Boot showing HD2 having an error (happened multiple times both before and after installing OS in it):

[image: booting]

This is possibly unrelated but under "Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings > Change advanced power settings" I have my processor options set as shown below (I have it that way for about a year or more), I don't remember how I came across this when I changed it to that but I was getting some random PC restarts if left at 100%, I already tried lowering it a bit since the current problem started but it didn't help.

[image: power settings]

I don't have other computers to test things directly in a different machine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Whichever HD I have for boot makes clicky and/or screechy-ish noises

If hard drive is clicking, and it wasn't always clicking, it is failing.

Unplug it and stop using it until you get a new install going, and then recover what you can using something like Robocopy (part of a windows install).

Robocopy can mirror a directory, can skip files already copied, and can accept a list of exclusions should specific files be a problem due to bad sectors.

I have successfully cloned a failing drive also, but success will depend greatly on where the damage is.

Comment: Both HDs started showing symptoms of hardware malfunction simultaneously, I didn't get both at the same time, 1 of them is like 5 years old, the other about 1 or so, I find it hard to believe they both would just start dying on me like that, hence my doubts.

Comment: Intermittent drive detection at BIOS/UEFI can be also related to the SATA controller of the motherboard. SMART reporting both drives as healthy suggests exactly that, a problem in the MB, not the drives themselves. Confirm it by attaching them to a known good PC, the remaining troubleshoot being obvious (I think).

Comment: If they are clicking they are failing. period

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to replace both drives.
Seagate ST####DM### drives are generally terrible drives.  Drives of approx 300gb size are generally really old, and getting ready to fail of old age.

Replace the 300gb drive with a 500/512gb samsung SSD.  Get a 2tb hgst hard drive to replace the other one.  They can be had for approx $60